# How Do I Read a File in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I am familiar with Ruby and am trying to write a program in Crystal.

I have a file called `special_file.txt` that I want to read in my Crystal program, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal is inspired by Ruby syntax and so you can often read and perform File operations in a similar manner. For example, Crystal has a [`File class`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2/File.html)class which is an instance of the [`IO class`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2/IO.html#read%28slice%3ABytes%29-instance-method) containing a `read` method.

To read a file's contents on your filesystem you can instantiate a `File` object and invoke the `gets_to_end` method coming from the `IO` super class:

```rb
file = File.new("path/to/file")
content = file.gets_to_end
file.close
```

The `gets_to_end` method reads an entire `IO` objects data to a `String` variable.

You can also use a block invocation to achieve a similar result:

```rb
# Implicit close with `open`
content = File.open("path/to/file") do |file|
  file.gets_to_end
end
```

Finally, the most idiomatic way to read the contents of an entire file would be the one line:

```
# Shortcut:
content = File.read("path/to/file")
```